# DataGrip/Intellij allow blank lines (semicolon separator) in Oracle SQL queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, intellij-idea, plsql, datagrip

In IntelliJ (and, I presume, DataGrip), up until a few weeks ago I was able to have blank lines in my SQL queries if I changed the dialect from "Oracle" to "Oracle SQL*Plus".

For example, these queries would be valid and would be executable so long as they were separated with a semicolon:

```
select *

from some.table;

select

    foo.a,
    foo.b,
    foo.c,
    
    bar.d,
    bar.e,
    bar.f

from foo
join bar on foo.id = bar.id;
```

... Now though, it thinks a blank line is the query separator, not a semicolon.

Any idea how I can get this functionality back?

Comment: Are you sure that it worked? Please see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3746

Comment: @s0xzwasd Certainly, it's been working for over a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I killed my `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJ*` directory and now it's working again. Not much of an answer I suppose. That said - I don't think it's well-known feature of the dialect, so instead of deleting the question I'll state it explicitly here in hopes it helps someone:

**Switch your dialect to "Oracle SQL*Plus" and you can have blank lines in your Oracle SQL queries.**